# Can we get a way to accent Yún?

Tags: discussion

### The Arduino Yún board, has an accent in it's name.

Unless you're using a modified/Spanish/Italian keyboard, it's hard to add the accent. It obviously isn't a huge deal, but I thought it might be something to think about. Could we:

- Just ignore it? (Note: I didn't tag it [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) if we wanted to ignore it)
- Add an accent symbol on the toolbar?
- Have some sort of script that automatically renames the instances of "Yun"

[image: Toolbar screenshot]

### Technically, we're misspelling a board's name on purpose. Is this even a big deal?

Comment: I don't think it's a huge deal. I don't know how hard it is to add a toolbar button but I still don't think it adds too much/any value.

Comment: This is probably not worth the effort. It is unlikely there will be any confusion without the accent on *Yun*.

Comment: I don't think it is a big deal, but it is _nice_ to get things looking right... regardless, we have three excellent examples, in the answers below, as to how to obtain a "ú".... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're working on Windows, try holding the left **Alt** key and type **163** on the numpad (the cluster of number keys at the right-hand side of many conventional keyboards). That should give you the accented **ú** character.

It may only work on American/British English systems.

For laptops/notebooks, you may have to enable num lock or similar to use part of the main keyboard as a numpad.

Comment: +1; works for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Mac OS. You can get the accent by pressing

> **alt+e** followed by **u**.

I don't see a special need for an extra icon in the toolbar.

Comment: on OSX Lion+ (i think), hold `u` and then press 4 when a menu comes up

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if HTML entities like `&uacute;` pruduce Yún in stackexchange markdown? ... it seems they do.

This is handy if you have a tenkeyless keyboard or can't remember decimal numbers for every accented character.

Comment: Good suggestion. I don't think HTML entities will work everywhere though, e.g. in question titles and comments. For example: &uacute;